# org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed

Tags: solr, solrj, solr6

***Using solr server version 6.6 and solrj 6.6.***

Currently the solr cores are created over glusterfs mounted partition. 
There is enough space for the solr cores on the mounted volume too.
Also, for some cores this issue is not seen but for others there is a consistent failure and the below mentioned exception is thrown.

**Exception chain:**
**org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id WI:5-1-8 to the index; possible analysis error.**

Any idea / workaround would be appreciated. :)

Comment: In the exception stack trace, i also see this  :   Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: Underlying file changed by an external force at 2017-12-18T16:33:01.144935Z, (lock=NativeFSLock(path=/data_de_de/data/index/write.lock,impl=sun.nio.ch.FileLockImpl[0:9223372036854775807 exclusive valid],creationTime=2017-12-18T16:33:02.057688Z))

Answer (score 1):

The SOLR server pod when deployed in kubernets used to claim for  a persistent volume of type glusterfs with access mode : RWX (Read Write Many).

> After creating a new peristent volume and volume claim of storage
>   class : cinder ( default open stack block storage) and with access
>   mode set to RWO (Read Write Once) and using it for the solr server
>   pod, we were able to get rid of the SolrException

. Looks like lucene(in solr) does not play well with glusterfs partition which has read-write permissions assigned for diff pods. Looks like it takes a lot of time to sync new file changes and hence lucene was not able to take locks when required and immediately failed saying that many external forces are trying to lock write.lock file in a solr core. So dont use a shared gluster fs parition for your solr cores.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ends up here looking for an answer, we were getting this error message because the hard drive on our solr machine was full. We deleted some log files and restarted the solr service and it resolved the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue just a couple of days back. Using `Solr 8.9.0` and due to enormous logs in the drive, it went out of space. The Solr Data Shard was in the same location.

After archiving log files still could not insert documents into Solr due to following error. It seems `Solr` keeps no space error somewhere in it.

```
org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed
```

Solution: The **Solr Restart** is the way to go.

After re-starting Solr, it started working as usual without any errors in the Solr Admin UI.

```
solr-8.9.0/bin/solr stop (Linux)

solr-8.9.0/bin/solr start (Linux)
```